# What is the relationship between products and categories in Magento?

Tags: magento2

What is the relationship between products and categories in Magento?

A. Products may be assigned to zero or more categories

B. Product to category relation is dynamically defined by Catalog Product Rules

C. Each product belongs to zero or one category

D. Each product always belongs to one category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q.What is the relationship between products and categories in Magento?

**Ans**-Products may be assigned to zero or more categories